# How to change the featured measure value of jqBulletGraph?

Tags: jquery, jqchart

I started using jqBulletGraph jquery plugin. I am trying to find a way how to set featured measure's value.
Can someone help me?

Thanks,
John Zachery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to set featured measure's value of jqBulletGraph you should try the following code snippet:

```
 featuredMeasures:
                [
                    {
                        value: 80,
                        fillStyle: featuredMeasureGradient,
                        innerOffset: 0.4,
                        outerOffset: 0.6
                    }
                ]
```

Please note that the "value: 80" shows the value of the featuredMeasure of the jquery bullet graph. 
To see the full example please click here: http://www.jqchart.com/jquery/gauges/BulletGraph/FeaturedMeasures

Disclamer: I work for jqChart.